# Direct call via the repeaters

Tags: repeater, dmr, brandmeister

Is it possible and if, how does it work, to establish direct DMR call between two stations through different repeaters? Does it work in the similar way as opening temporary groups on repeaters or some other magic is involved.

As a example scenario, let assume that I(XX1AAA) want to connect with (XX9BBB). We are not in the range of the common repeater and we would like to establish private (not via the TG) connection.

I assume that simply calling XX9BBB from XX1AAA will not work as no repeater know where XX9BBB, or do it? Is it so that network will route my call to the repeater where XX9BBB was last saw? Or maybe XX9BBB have to make a call to me at the same time for link to be opened?

Comment: expand a bit on what you mean by "private connection." Do you mean encrypted or somehow hidden from everyone else?

Comment: @webmarc private as a oposte to group

Comment: DMR repeaters use a layer topology, and thus once "connected" can repeat traffic to and from each other based on link traffic. It's unclear to me what you are asking because most repeaters just connect to others, and once your specific handset is accepted the traffic to/from it is just handled. What exactly are you trying to achieve?